# unknown command ".network.genesisProfile" for "yq"

Tags: kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, kubernetes-helm

I am working on a repo https://github.com/adarshaJha/PIVT#scaled-up-raft-network

and  when i run this command :

`helm install ./hlf-kube --name hlf-kube -f samples/simple/network.yaml -f samples/simple/crypto-config.yaml`

i get this error :

**unknown command ".network.genesisProfile" for "yq"**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer that my yq version was 2.2.1 and in the [requirements](https://github.com/APGGroeiFabriek/PIVT#requirements) it's mentioned that **jq 1.5+ and yq 2.6+** are required, i upgraded to the latest version and it resolved.